# Multiple windows mac application

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindowcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I want to make a multiple windows mac application and I am stuck with the multiple window part !

I can display some windows by creating a xib file and using this method :

```
-(void)popView:(NSString *)viewName {
    _windowController = [[AddProdutWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:viewName];
    [_windowController showWindow:nil];
}
```

With 
`@property (strong, nonatomic) AddProdutWindowController *windowController;`

in my header file and `AddProductViewController` inherit from `NSWindowViewController`

I have linked a subclass of `NSViewController` in Xcode to my `xib` file.

Now I want to send some datas to my new view and show them in some `NSTextField` and I have not a single clue how to do it !

I'm very confused with the `WindowsController` and `ViewController`, I don't exactly know how / where use them.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

your firstWindowController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class SecondWindowController;

@interface ResultWindowController : NSWindowController{
   SecondWindowController *swc;
}
@property  (assign) NSNumber *xyz;
...
```

your firstWindowController.m:

```
#import "FirstWindowController.h"
#import "SecondWindowController.h"

@implementation FirstWindowController
@synthesize xyz;


- (IBAction)openSecondWindow:(id *)sender {
if (!swc)
{
    swc = [[SecondWindowController alloc] init];
}
[Swc setFwc:self];
[Swc showWindow:self];
```

your secondWindowController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class FirstWindowController;
@interface SecondWindowController : NSWindowController {
   FirstWindowController *fwc;
}
@property (retain) IBOutlet FirstWindowController *fwc;

@end
```

your secondWindowController.m:

```
#import "SecondWindowController.h"
#import "FirstWindowController.h"

@implementation SecondWindowController
@synthesize fwc;


- (id)init
{
if(![super initWithWindowNibName:@"SecondWindow"])
    return nil;
NSLog(@"_init: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]));

return self;
}

- (void)windowDidLoad
{
[super windowDidLoad];

NSLog(@"swc didload self=%p", self); //thats your second window controller

NSLog(@"fwc value is %@", fwd.xyz);  // here you should be able to see the value from FirtsWindowController
}
```